# Bootstrap checkbox won't fire the change event

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So, I have a checkbox that I made using the Bootstrap methodology. I am trying to show or hide some divs depending on whether or not this checkbox is checked. I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="checkbox" id="partner-div">
                  <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chkPartner" />
                      Check here if you are an Acelity partner or representative submitting a video on behalf of someone else.
                  </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group acelity-partner" style="display:none">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="txtRepFirstName">Representative's First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRepFirstName" placeholder="Representative's First Name'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group acelity-partner" style="display:none">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="txtRepLastName">Representative's Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRepLastName" placeholder="Representative's Last Name'" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group acelity-partner" style="display:none">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <label for="txtRepEmail">Representative's Email Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtRepEmail" placeholder="Representative's Email Address'" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

And the following JQuery inside the document.ready:

```
$("#chkPartner").change(function (event) {
                  if ($("#chkPartner").prop("checked")) {
                      $(".acelity-partner").show();
                  } else {
                      $(".acelity-partner").hide();
                  }
              });
```

Can't get the event to fire.

Comment: Is there any error on console? Your code works for me (without bootstrap).

Comment: Is your jQuery in a $(document).ready?

Comment: No errors in the console and yes, the code is inside of $(document).ready with other code that already works

Comment: Since I didn't think anyone would believe me, I have made a screen cast of the code in action. I have added a testMe function that is tied to the onClick of the checkbox. It shows an alert regarding $("#chkPartner).is(":checked") and as you can see it always says "not checked"


http://screencast.com/t/GQniCzndke8

Comment: It does the same thing if I change the code to check if ($("#chkPartner").prop("checked")=="checked")


http://screencast.com/t/fCzgZ80c9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into this very strange problem, I solved it using toggle(). What I did was simply create a function called toggleRep() and called it from the onclick of the checkbox. It simply toggles the visibility of the rep fields as I wanted. Not sure why the "normal" way doesn't work, but this way works perfectly:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="checkbox" id="partner-div">
                  <label>
                      <input type="checkbox" id="chkPartner" onclick="toggleRep();" />
                      Check here if you are an Acelity partner or representative submitting a video on behalf of someone else.
                  </label>
              </div>
            </div>
```

and when clicked that calls this function:

```
function toggleRep() {
              $(".acelity-partner").toggle();
              if ($(".acelity-partner").is(":visible")) {
                  // do nothing
              } else {
                  //clear fields of their values
                  $(".acelity-rep").val("");
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `if ($("#chkPartner").prop("checked") == "checked")`. It may not be returning the null you expect when false.

Comment: When I add if ($("#chkPartner").prop("checked") != "checked") {
                  alert("checked");
              } I get the alert when the page is loaded because the checkbox is not checked.